# Regex to match a string without a specific tailing word

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex to match a string without a specific tailing word.
for example: 
   I want to match any string but without a tailing word "apple".

```
1. input:   this is apple
   output:  I don't want to match this

2. input:  this is apple store
   output:  match (apple is not the tailing word, although it is there)
```

I tried this one with negative lookahead, but failed:

```
(?!.*music$)
```

this one will not match case 1, but also not match case 2.  I want to "not match" case 1, but "match" case2.

Comment: what about trailing spaces?

Comment: is this what you are looking for?
`/apple$/`
it will look only for trailing word as apple.
It works in vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use start anchor `^` before your negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*\bapple$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oH6gC5/1)

This will fail the match if last word is `apple` in a line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative look behind:

```
.*(?<!\bapple)$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nI5dH1/6)

Comment: Yes.. and idk if you observed. it also takes less steps to match the same string :)